# enum should not be used as identifier, since it is a keyword from source level 1.5 error in maven project

Tags: java, maven, enums, myeclipse

I created a maven project in myeclipse project as:

> 1) mvn clean install
>
> 2) mvn eclipse:myeclipse

I, then, imported project into myeclipse but I got loads of build errors like

enum should not be used as identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5...

I have used maven 3.2.5 for building and creating project with maven.

I am using myeclipse 10.7.0 with Java 1.7.0 JDK.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you have a project that is defined as a Java 1.4 (or earlier) project, but you have Java 1.5 code (enums) and that is producing the Java editor validation messages. Check your pom to see if it defines a Java source level. If so, ensure it is correct, or else define one, or change the java compiler level in the project properties. If you change the pom, make sure you right click on the project and select Maven4MyEclipse->Update Project.

Just an additional note. You do not need to run mvn eclipse:myeclipse to import a maven project and this is likely to result in a bad MyEclipse project as that Maven plug-in is not provided with MyEclipse. Instead, use Import->Maven4MyEclipse->Existing Maven Projects.

A further note is that 10.7 is no longer fully supported, it's recommended that you switch to the latest release (2015 Stable 1.0 or 2015 CI 11).

Answer (score 2):

You have a variable with name `enum`. Since `enum` is a reserved word in java 1.5 or higher you should rename the variable.

For more information you should add your code and the stacktrace.

Comment: I don't have any variable/identifier with any keyword of Java. Below is the error details:

Comment: I don't have any variable/identifier with any keyword of Java. Below is the error details:
Description Resource Path Location Type
'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5 on Convert.java /STM/src/main/java/com/tma/sqlserver/stm/command line 9 Java Problem. There are 3908 similar errors. :-(

Comment: public enum Set {
        APPI, APPINFO, ARRAY, ARRAYSIZE
    }

Comment: this is how enum is declared in convert.java.

Comment: @user82504 So here `enum` is an Object? Please add the class named enum.

Comment: This is a enumeration type i.e. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html and not a class.

Comment: @user82504 for which source level do you compile?

Comment: Java 1.7.0 with Myeclipse 10.7.0

Comment: @user You can change the source level in eclipse. so the java version do you use is not the source level.

Comment: I already tried that Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE changed the source level to 1.7. Moreover, I have changed the source level through myeclipse.ini files as well. Moreover, I have removed JDK from project properties and then added again. But nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by installing latest version of the eclipse. It automatically installed the m2e for myeclipse and compiled the projects without any errors.

Comment: If you updated due to part of my answer, please at least mark my answer up. Thanks.